# Spoof MAC address in Windows 7: Bypass

Tags: windows-7, mac-address, spoofing

I am trying to spoof the MAC address of my new Win7 laptop. To do so I tried specifying an alternate value from the Device Manager which took no effect. I also tried from the registry, as per other threads here, to no avail. Interestingly I also found the registry contained a path 000X\Ndi\params\NetworkAddress\default REG_SZ, but changing that had no effect either :(

I can only guess I share the same issue here: http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2096480 as the wireless adaptor is the same brand bundled with the same operating system. So my question is - is there anything *better* I can do to achieve a spoofed physical address than rollback the drivers to some older version?

Comment: you can do it the easy way http://www.gorlani.com/portal/Home/Projects/MacMakeup.aspx or http://www.klcconsulting.net/Change_MAC_w2k.htm

Comment: Have you tried turning the adapter off and on again? (Alternatively, reboot.)

Comment: @grawity - several times, both ways.

Comment: @00101010 I installed SMAC and promptly installed after it told me it could only change the mac address to one predefined string unless I paid it forty bucks. The other link specifies it only works up to Vista... I'll give it a go later but I doubt that it'll work unless someone has specifically programmed a way to avoid this extra "security".

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Technitium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/), a free program that let's you change your MAC Address. Worked for me on my Windows 10 laptop!

Answer (score -2):

Just install CommView for WiFi. You don't have to know what does that program. But it will change your WiFi adapter's driver and let you change it's MAC address from adapter's settings.

To do it, download and install that program, go to WiFi adapter's properties -> Configure -> find "Network Address" or "MAC address" or "Physical Address" and change it.